# I am learning quick sort using javaScript and and the code is not working where i am making mistake?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, quicksort

**It takes array as a input
and return a sorted array using quick sort**
**I am getting a error of maximum call stack size exceeded**
***I tried different approaches but I think its the closes one that i came with 
What different approach i Should make ?***

```
     function quickSort(arr){
    // grab the pivot from the start of the array
    let i = 0;
    // store the current pivot index in a variable
    let pivot = arr[i];
    // end variable of array.
    let j = 0;
    let k = j;
    *// loop through the array from the start until the end*
    function helper(arry){
        *// if the pivot is greater than the current element ,increment the pivot index variable and then swap the current       element with the element at the pivot index* 
        while(i < j && i<arry.length){
            if(pivot > arry[k]){
                let swap = arry[i];
                arry[i] = arry[k]
                arry[k] = swap
                j++;
            }

            k++;

            if(j == k){
                i++;
            }
        }
        helper(arry)
        if(arry.length == i ){
            return
        }

    }
        helper(arr);
        return arr;
    *// Swap the starting element(ie; the pivot) with the index* 
}
```

Comment: Your code is recursive which is fine but it never stops being recursive and just keeps running, hence your exception.

Answer (score 0):

Step-1: You have to pick a pivot. This could be randomly selected or the middle one. Here we select the last element of the array.

Step-2: Put all the items smaller than the pivot value to the left and larger than the pivot value to the right.

Step-3:Repeat the step-2 for both left and right side of the pivot (pick a pivot, put all item smaller than the pivot to the left and larger on the right)

Explain the code
Call Quick sort: Pass the array and pass left and right to the quickSort function. For the first call, left would be the index of the first element which is 0 and right would be the index of the last element which would be length -1.

Select Pivot: We select pivot as the last index of the array.

Call Partition function: After calculating the pivot, we send the pivot to the partition function. In the partition function we pass array, pivot index, left and right.

partitionIndex: In the partition function, we keep move all the items smaller than the pivot value to the left and larger than pivot value to the right. We have to keep track of the position of the partition. so that we can split the array into two parts in the next step. This tracking of the index where we partition the array is done by using partitionIndex variable. the initial value is left.

Swap function: This is just a helper function to swap values of the array.

move elements: we start a for loop from the left, and if the values is smaller than the pivot values we swap it with the position of the partitionIndex and increase the value of the partitionIndex. If the value is bigger, we don't do anything. We keep going until the element before the last element (remember last element is the pivot)

place pivot After moving all the smallest element to the left, we swap the last element (pivot value) with the partitionIndex. By doing this, the pivot sits where it suppose to sit when the full array is sorted. As all elements left to it smaller and all element right to it is bigger. End of the function partition, return the partitionIndex

Repeat the process: Now come back to quickSort function. when you get the partitionIndex, apply quickSort for the left side of the array and right side of the array. keep doing it until left is smaller than right.

```
function quickSort(arr, left, right){
   var len = arr.length, 
   pivot,
   partitionIndex;


  if(left < right){
    pivot = right;
    partitionIndex = partition(arr, pivot, left, right);

   //sort left and right
   quickSort(arr, left, partitionIndex - 1);
   quickSort(arr, partitionIndex + 1, right);
  }
  return arr;
}

function partition(arr, pivot, left, right){
   var pivotValue = arr[pivot],
       partitionIndex = left;

   for(var i = left; i < right; i++){
    if(arr[i] < pivotValue){
      swap(arr, i, partitionIndex);
      partitionIndex++;
    }
  }
  swap(arr, right, partitionIndex);
  return partitionIndex;
}

function swap(arr, i, j){
   var temp = arr[i];
   arr[i] = arr[j];
   arr[j] = temp;
}
```